# How to use the MarkLogic thesaurus API on phrases?

Tags: marklogic, thesaurus

In Marklogic we can expand a search to include terms from a thesaurus as well as the terms entered in the search.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace thsr="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/thesaurus" at "/MarkLogic/thesaurus.xqy";

cts:search(
doc("/Docs/hamlet.xml")//LINE,
thsr:expand(
    cts:word-query("weary"), 
    thsr:lookup("/myThsrDocs/thesaurus.xml", "weary"),
    (), 
    (), 
    () )
)
```

Question is how to support below cases :

- Apple AND Orange
- Apple NOT Orange
- Apple - Orange
- Apple + Orange
- form: 10-K
- co: Apple
- Apple Orange form:[10-K]
- “Apple and Orange”
- “Apple” Orange

Answer (score 1):

I don't think thesaurus expansion is intended for these cases.

Instead, consider using the Search API and expanding the grammar to include variants on the boolean operators:

```
http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/search-api#id_44520
```

To map form: and co: to the same index, again, consider using the Search API and defining multiple constraints for the same index:

```
http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/search-api#id_95820
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `search:parse` to parse the query string, yielding cts:query XML. Then use a recursive `typeswitch` function to walk the XML. Use thesaurus expansion on `cts:word` and `cts:word` terms.